# NodeIterator vs Xpath for DOM iterating/finding in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Which is better to use when iterating over DOM elements or finding a a set of DOM elements.  is Xpath faster?

Answer (score 0):

Xpath is more clean.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I don't know if it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a group of elements that are at different hiearchical levels and different attributes of interest then you should use Xpath.

If you just want to "iterate" one by one over a set of elements then just use the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

The dojo team did some research about when XPath is faster for their `dojo.query` interface.

See their [Blog Post about it.](http://o.dojotoolkit.org/node/336?PHPSESSID=c95165d3e75384d26c1098f60ee2446d)

Answer (score 0):

according to this post "The DOM traversal code is about four times faster than the XPath code."
http://www.sklar.com/blog/archives/85-Speed-DOM-traversal-vs.-XPath-in-PHP-5.html